# Laravel CLI 'sail artisan' returns 'no such service' after updating 'service name' in docker-compose.yml

Tags: php, laravel, docker

After creating a new [Laravel project](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/installation#getting-started-on-macos) via [Laravel Sail](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sail#installation), a new project is created within a Docker container.  When I updated the associated 'docker-composer.yml' file to rename the 'laravel.test' service, I closed it and rebuilt sail with the expectation that this would incorporate my changes to the service name using `sail build --no-cache`.
Ever since then, the command `sail artisan` returns an error '**ERROR: No such service: Laravel.test**'
Exhaustive searches yielded no help.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I have created a customized solution that is based off of Laravel's installation.  It includes installation of XDebug and the latest node.js and NPM.  It is a fully functional solution that also has all source code readily available [sail.StonePlayground.com](https://sail.StonePlayground.com)

I welcome comments.

--- Previous Answer ---
In the `./vendor/bin/sail` file there are a few locations where I replaced 'laravel.test' with the value I have set in 'docker-composer.yml' (myApp.local).  This also matches my '.env' APP_URL (less the http://).  All is now working well!
I'm hoping this post is helpful to others who may run into a similar situation.

UPDATE: I found a much simpler way to accomplish this with no need to edit the vendor files.  Just add `APP_SERVICE="myApp.local"` (or whatever your local URL is) to your .env file.

Comment: Definitely helpful! Thank you.

Comment: Inside the  .env file, I matched the `APP_URL` with `APP_SERVICE`  (without the http://) but the the error is still there. 

Did I misunderstand your explanation?

Comment: @alexandru-cristian The implied/possible missed  step is that you renamed laravel.test container to match the value of  **bold** `APP_SERVICE`

Answer (score 17):

I found a really great [article](https://tech.osteel.me/posts/you-dont-need-laravel-sail) about this topic and Larvel Sail in general.

What I realized after reading it is that the error says exactly what is happening, as usual. Your `APP_SERVICE` name has to match with the service name of your actuall laravel app container in `docker-compose.yaml` file, which is by default `laravel.test`. When you rename it, do what [George](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65982604/14303211) suggested with `APP_SERVICE` `.env` variable. What is really important here though, is your service name, not `APP_URL`.

Answer (score 1):

When I read [sail customization](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sail#sail-customization) I misread this paragraph:

> After customizing your Sail installation, you may wish to change the
> image name for the laravel.test service in your application's
> docker-compose.yml file. [...] Assigning a unique name to the
> laravel.test service image is particularly important if you are using
> Sail to develop multiple Laravel applications on a single machine:

I thought this means I should rename the **service name** and had the same error message that you had, and in this case setting `APP_SERVICE` is the right solution. However, it only states to rename the **image name**. Changing the **image name** in `docker-compose.yml` does work without adding additional environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was run the container "manually":

```
docker compose run -d -i laravel.test
```